# Search for exact text fails if text is followed by punctuation marks

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

The search will only return results, when the whole word matches, therefore you can't search for substrings. Unfortunately punctuation marks are handled as part of the word.

Searching *["lambda architecture" is:answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22lambda%20architecture%22%20is%3Aanswer)* will return 2 results.

<kbd>[image: 2 results]</kbd>

Searching *["lambda architecture." is:answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22lambda%20architecture.%22%20is%3Aanswer)* will return 3 results.

<kbd>[image: 3 results]</kbd>

Note that only one result is returned by both searches. You'll also get other results when searching with a colon at the end.

Please ignore punctuation marks in posts on search, so that I'll see at least 4 answers with both searches.
If I search explicitly for a special character such results should be more relevant and therefore at the top.

Comment: On the other hand, ignoring punctuation will make it hard to search for language operators (something you can't do with Google, but can do with SO search).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I believe the intent is to ignore unasked-for punctuation in the results, not in the query itself.

Comment: Yup, I ran into this when there was a term in the title with smart quotes. See [Searching for text in smart quotes in dumb quotes doesn't work? “test: text” “xtest xtext” “dumb quotes”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202417/225437), [Search for quoted text doesn't include answers where text is quoted in title “unlikely word combination”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202610/225437), and [How can I search for questions with the error message “application: not a procedure” in the Scheme tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202612/225437).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: Good point. If you search for operators such posts should be more relevant and therefore show up first. I added that.

Comment: Searching for "git-svn" as a specific string (referring to a package) failed even though I know that there are already a few questions on the subject. This was in the context of Linux/Unix rather than StackOverflow. The result included a match on "git/svn" which told me that the search function itself doesn't understand that if I wanted to search for git followed by svn with random stuff in between I would not have used the quotes that are supposed to indicate that exact matches are desired.