# Search for !! yields nothing

Tags: discussion, search

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript) has the title: **What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?**

Yet searching for **!!** doesn't find it, why is that? Is **!** removed from searches for security reasons?

Comment: Agreed, did search but didn't see that, will close now - thanks

Comment: Side note: I think this may be a side effect of this feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275100